# How do stop my character from going through the ground

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So i am trying to make a fighting game and i have fixed so i can jump and so on by making my y speed += 1 every frame to make it act like gravity and when i press the jump key the y speed -=14. But when i use higher than -=14 for example -=20 the character clips through the ground.

i am using this kind off collison detection

```
collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, object_list, False)
    for col in collisions:
        if type(col) == Solid:
            if (self.rect.top < col.rect.bottom and self.rect.bottom > 
                col.rect.bottom):
                self.rect.top = col.rect.bottom

            if (self.rect.bottom > col.rect.top and self.rect.y < col.rect.top):
                self.rect.bottom = col.rect.top
                self.yspeed = 0
                self.jump = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your **fighter** is falling so fast that it passes the platform in one update of the loop...

There are a few ways to solve this issue, the most simple one is to update its position a few times and check for collisions each time...

```
#example ...
for i in range(4): # split the change into smaller steps ...
    self.rect.y += self.velocity_y /4.0
    collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, object_list, False)
    ... #all your collisions checks here ...
```

Comment: worked to an extent but now  when i jump near an solid that i created the character gets stuck to it if i hold movement key towards it and if i jump towards it, i get launched really high and when i walk of the solid  i fall through  the ground but not when i jump of it.

Comment: i think i know why now. Because every frame the yspeed downwards increase by 1 and therefore when i walk of the platform its not resetted to 0 so i get a too high of a speed and get clipped through the ground i guess.

Comment: Indeed, it is also wise to update y - check collisions - update y - check collisions and so on so you won't have such issues ...